# How to add tooltips and/or links to placeholder text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a textarea with placeholder text like this:

```
<textarea tabindex="4" placeholder="Type here. Use Markdown, 
BBCode, or HTML to format. Drag or paste images." id="ember1313" 
class="d-editor-input ember-text-area ember-view"></textarea>
```

I'm thinking my users probably won't know Markdown, BBCode, or HTML. It would be awesome if I could turn these words into links to articles explaining each one. A separate tool tip onmouseover of each of these three words might work as well.

Comment: you can't add link or title to placeholder content

Comment: @Sand no. it's not

Comment: @Redo same problem different asking format just like a cover to an original song.

Comment: @Sand except one is a jquery function the other is an html5 element....

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('textarea').blur(function() {
  var inputVal = $(this).val(),
      titleText = $(this).attr('placeholder');
  if ( inputVal !=  '' ) {
    $(this).tooltip({
    title: titleText,
    trigger: 'focus'
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm looking to get a link or tooltip attached to single words within the placeholder text.

Answer (score 0):

Like this :

[Working Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/ko0o5c6L/)

Html :

```
<textarea tabindex="4" title="Type here. Use Markdown, 
BBCode, or HTML to format. Drag or paste images." id="ember1313" 
class="d-editor-input ember-text-area ember-view"></textarea>
```

CSS :

```
.tooltip{
            display: inline;
            position: relative;
        }

        .tooltip:hover:after{
            background: #333;
            background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
            border-radius: 5px;
            bottom: 26px;
            color: #fff;
            content: attr(title);
            left: 20%;
            padding: 5px 15px;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 98;
            width: 220px;
        }

        .tooltip:hover:before{
            border: solid;
            border-color: #333 transparent;
            border-width: 6px 6px 0 6px;
            bottom: 20px;
            content: "";
            left: 50%;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 99;
        }
```

Comment: That just turns the placeholder text into a tooltip. I want to leave the placeholder text and turn three words into clickable links or have tool tips descriptions over just those three words

Comment: Do you want to show those three words(Markdown, BBCode, or HTML) into placeholder or elsewhere ?

Comment: I'm looking to have something equivalent of me being able to wrap Markdown, BBCode, and HTML in link tags while still being my placeholder text.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement Tooltip (as the intention is to show information to the end-users) provided by bootstrap :https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/tooltips/

OR Jquery Tooltips: https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

Examples are mentioned there for your reference.

Comment: I know how to make a tooltip... how would you go about having one appear onmouseover of a singe word within the placeholder text of a textarea?

Answer (score 0):

See the updated fiddle i hope it helps you :

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ko0o5c6L/4/)

```js
$('textarea').hover(function(){
    $('.d-editor-input').tooltip({
    title: titleText,
    trigger: 'focus'
    });
})
```

```css
.tooltip{
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
}

.tooltip:hover:after{
    background: #333;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    border-radius: 5px;
    bottom: 26px;
    color: #fff;
    content: attr(title);
    left: 20%;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 98;
    width: 220px;
}

.tooltip:hover:before{
    border: solid;
    border-color: #333 transparent;
    border-width: 6px 6px 0 6px;
    bottom: 20px;
    content: "";
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea tabindex="4" title="Type here. Use Markdown, 
BBCode, or HTML to format. Drag or paste images." id="ember1313" 
class="d-editor-input ember-text-area ember-view"></textarea>
```